# Energy harvesting from a current transformer

Tags: current-measurement, low-power, energy-harvesting

Looking into developing a mobile GSM/3G/SMS current monitoring widget which measures and powers the circuitry from a current transformer(s).

One of the major hurdles is gathering enough power to store and use to do something useful. So is there any energy harvesting IC's which specialize in this area? Bearing in mind the same CT will be also used for measurement of current.

Comment: Don't ask for a technical discussion because this isn't that type of site. That link doesn't say the device is totally current powered.

Comment: It depends entirely on the amount of current flowing, and your burdon resistor.  Is there any kind of real question here?

Comment: Please read the [help] to learn how to ask good questions that get good answers. The current question isn't a good fit. A specific use-case might enable people to give more helpful answers.

Comment: I'll also chime in and say that mucking around three-phase high-power systems without knowing *exactly* what you are doing is a recipe for disaster or even death. Panoramic Power seem to have done all this hard work already; if you want to implement something like this, just use their already-designed and proven-safe product.

Comment: Well. SE sure showed him. He came back a few times but 'we' managed to drive him off. Despite his obviously reasonable knowledge level and the utterly and completely clear and reasonable question, we managed to find enough people to vote  to close because, by their own admission, theyfound that despite the clear and obvious and focused request that it was "... unclear what you're asking." Don't we do well! :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-(

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you will run into is that a current transformer (CT) is only accurate when the voltage across the secondary (output) is as close to zero as possible.

In order to power a device from that CT, you have to allow the output voltage to rise to a level that is high enough for the circuit to function. That degrades the CT accuracy.

The loss of accuracy can be pretty extreme, depending on the CT turns / current ratio.

There is a possible solution to that problem - use a CT to provide the power that your circuit requires, then use something else to actually measure the current. That could be a hall-effect current sensor or even another CT who's primary is in series with the CT that is providing the circuit power.

That second CT is, of course, properly terminated for the highest accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the specifications of the current transformers that are on the market. Current transformers like the one in your link are called "split-core current transformers." The power range can probably be 10 watts or more, but you would need to analyze what you want to do in detail.